# SAPUi5 File Uploader sets WebKitFormBoundary

Tags: javascript, http, sapui5

I try to upload an image using the `sap.ui.unified.FileUploader`. My code looks like this:

View:

```
<u:FileUploader id="fileUploader" uploadUrl="{parts:[{path:'/d/results/0/ThingId'}],formatter: '.formatter.imageURL'}" sendXHR="true"/>
```

Controller:

```
var oFileUploader = this.getView().byId("fileUploader");
oFileUploader.addHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
    name: "Content-Type",
    value: ?
}));
oFileUploader.upload();
```

I tried several things as the value for the `Content-Type` header. When I don't use the header at all and read the file afterwards from the server it has a header and footer like `------WebKitFormBoundarymoQAeq4WVmJo82xE`. When I set it to `image/png` the server interprets it as an image, but I guess the server also adds the boundary to the image content. So, when I download it afterwards I get an image but it's just black.
I also read something about a value like `multipart/form-data;boundary=WebKitFormBoundary` but this has the same result on my server as no header at all.

When I send the same image from Postman, with no headers it works fine. As a requested here is a screenshot of how the request looks like in Postman (the Header is just the Authorization). 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<u:FileUploader useMultipart="false"
```